# Hide properties from querystring when using a strongly typed model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET Core, and attribute routing.

I have this strongly typed model

```
public Command
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

And this action

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("my route here")]
public IActionResult Foo(Command command) { ... }
```

So route looks like this

```
.../whatever/foo?id=5
```

But I want

```
.../whatever/foo/5
```

I tried changing the property to `int?` but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your route with input parameters in it.

```
.../whatever/foo/{id}
```

If you want to access the supplied parameter, you can add it as a method parameter.

```
public IActionResult Foo(Command command, int id) { ... }
```

Comment: It's a pity there is leaking/duplication of routing knowledge between the route (as a magic string) and the strongly typed model. This works, but I wish there were a better way.

Comment: You do not need the `int id` parameter - the `DefaultModelBinder` will bind to the `public int Id { get; set; }` property of the model because the names match

Comment: @StephenMuecke Agreed, but the first part of the answer is correct.

Comment: You can also be explicit about where the parameter is bound, since otherwise a user could construct a request with an id in both the querystring and in the URL, for instance. If you want to be explicit, you can use `[FromRoute]int id` for instance. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding